# Preventing Dionaea Service Identification

Tags: nmap, honeypot

I've been working on trying to prevent Dionaea service identification using articles such as [this](http://www.securityartwork.es/2014/06/05/avoiding-dionaea-service-identification/). I've managed to disguise most of the ports that dionaea utilizes. However, when scanning with nmap, ports 5060/tcp and 5061/tcp still show up as honeypot and ssl/honeypot services, respectively, and nmap identifies them as Dionaea Honeypot sipd.

Also, for some reason, port 5060/udp shows up as a sip service end point.

Does anyone have any idea how I can prevent dionaea from identifying those two ports as well? All of the online resources that talk about hiding dionaea don't really address hiding dionaea's sip services, since older versions of nmap don't appear to be capable of identifying those.

For reference, here is the line in nmap-service-probes that allows the software to identify the honeypot.

`match honeypot m|^SIP/2\.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nVia: SIP/2\.0/TCP nm;branch=foo\r\nFrom: sip:nm@nm;tag=root\r\nAccept: application/sdp\r\nTo: sip:nm2@nm2\r\nContact: sip:nm2@nm2\r\nCSeq: 42 OPTIONS\r\nAllow: REGISTER, OPTIONS, INVITE, CANCEL, BYE, ACK\r\nCall-ID: 50000\r\nAccept-Language: en\r\n\r\n| p/Dionaea Honeypot sipd/`